How to Debug Existing Reports in Jaspersoft Studio for SAP Field Service Management?
I’m currently working on fixing errors in a report created by someone else in Jaspersoft Studio for SAP Field Service Management (FSM). While troubleshooting, I’ve encountered challenges in identifying and resolving the issues in the report output.
A major difficulty is that the error encountered when generating the report in SAP FSM does not appear in Jaspersoft Studio during testing. This discrepancy makes it harder to pinpoint the source of the issue and effectively resolve it.
Please note that I’m not designing a new report but focusing on debugging an existing one. Additionally, I’m not using any Java applications; I’m working exclusively with Jaspersoft Studio and SAP FSM.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could share their tips, best practices, or tools for debugging reports in this context. Are there specific logs, settings, or workflows you recommend for efficiently identifying and fixing issues, especially in cases where errors occur only in the FSM environment?
Thank you in advance for your support and advice!
Best regards,
